# How to display conda's environment in zsh (not using oh-my-zsh)?

Tags: python, zsh, conda, ps1

I use **zsh** but **not equipted with oh-my-zsh**, since I cloned many git repos on my machine and oh-my-zsh's default theme or 'josh' theme makes it **very slow**, for `cd` and `ls` commands, etc.

Thus I delete oh-my-zsh and only use zsh's default recommended config, except adding some alias and path variables.

Now comes the question: I manage my python environment by **conda**, and no current enviroment name displayed in my prompt.

I have executed the command:

```sh
conda init zsh
```

And **re-open my terminal (default shell is zsh), still not display "(base)" or "(py36)" stuffs**.

How can I tell my terminal to show that stuff? The git branch does not matters for my work, but the current python version really matters, since DeepLearning related tools use many different python versions.

Comment: In my ~/.condarc, I previously didn't setting `changeps1: False`. And now I add `changeps1: True`, still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused due to this line in default zsh's config:

```sh
prompt adam1
```

Once delete that line, re-open terminal, conda environment are shown.

Comment: Where can I find this?

Comment: @Shehan Find it in your zsh config file, usually it is `~/.zshrc`

Comment: I don't have such a line. But still, conda env is not shown.

Answer (score 8):

For those users with oh-my-zsh

I add anaconda element in ~/.zshrc config file

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(anaconda ...ENVS)
```

and the conda env shows up

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using `oh-my-zsh` and have not copy-pasted the relevant sections from there, then the correct answer is that when you do `conda init zsh`, the environment variable `CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER` is introduced. You want to add that to your `PROMPT`. You should do so as part of the `precmd` function, so that the an updated value of the environment variable is shown every time a prompt is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```sh
# init your shell first
conda init zsh
source ~/.zshrc # refresh your shell
source activate base # (optional, on linux) activate base env
```

Comment: by running conda init zsh, some init lines wil be added to ~/.zshrc . Then do source ~/.zsh, is the same as re-open a shell. The last step you mentioned, source activate base, I didn't try, but it can also be put in ~/.zshrc.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved `changeps1: False` this line in `~/.condarc`,and restart my zsh, the `(base)` suddenly appear.

It takes effort to me!