# (oh-my-zsh) conda environment name does not show up in terminal

Tags: conda, zsh

(Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

In bash shell I see my current active conda environment `(base)`

However, in zsh shell I do not see it. (I can activate any shell but it won't show up)

Is there a way how I can enable it?

I did try methods from this post but it did not help...
[How to display conda's environment in zsh (not using oh-my-zsh)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033093/how-to-display-condas-environment-in-zsh-not-using-oh-my-zsh)